# r: create data frame with all possible options and number of variable combinations

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, combinations

This question might be obvious or asked already, but I can't find a solution:

I want to create a data frame with all possible combinations (and number of variables) such that it looks like the following example:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(variable =   1:4, 
                        a = c("gender", NA, NA, NA),
                        b = c("age", NA, NA, NA),
                        c = c("city", NA, NA, NA),
                        d = c("education", NA, NA, NA),
                        e = c("gender", "age", NA, NA),
                        f = c("gender", "city", NA, NA), 
                        g = c("gender", "education", NA, NA), 
                        h = c("age", "city", NA, NA), 
                        i = c("age", "education", NA, NA), 
                        j = c("city", "education", NA, NA), 
                        k = c("gender", "age", "city", NA), 
                        l = c("gender", "age", "education", NA), 
                        m = c("gender", "city", "education", NA),
                        n = c("gender", "age", "city", "education"))
```

I have too many variables, so it's not worth writing it out, and I want to avoid errors. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Can you show the input data used for creating this

Comment: the input data are maybe 15 column names of any data frame. or just `variables = c("gender", "age", "city", "education", "school", "income", "bmi", "SES", "...")`, or what input data do you need?  The computed data frame then of course has to have as many rows as there are variables.

Comment: Beware combinatorial explosion. With 15 variables you get 2 ^ 15 columns

Comment: What is your use case? If it is trying different models, there are better options out there: Lasso, Ridge, stepwise, etcetera

Comment: @Aurèle good point. I want to see the different combinations for multiple regression, based on reasoning, without using a function for model selection. I just want to see the possible combinations to try different regression models.

Comment: Anyway we're stuck after 26 combinations :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `combn`.  Get the `vector` of variable names, loop through the sequence of the `vector`, apply the `combn` on the `vector` with `m` specified as the sequence from the loop, convert to `data.frame` and `cbind` all the `list` elements together.  The `cbind.fill` from `rowr` is suitable to `fill` with `NA` for `list` elements that have less number of rows than the maximum row `data.frame`

```
library(rowr)
res <- do.call(cbind.fill, c(fill = NA, lapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) {
       m1 <- combn(v1, i)
       if(is.vector(m1)) as.data.frame.list(m1)  else as.data.frame(m1)})))
colnames(res) <- letters[seq_along(res)]
```

Or as @Moody_Mudskipper suggested,

```
res1 <- do.call(cbind.fill, c(fill = NA, lapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) combn(v1, i))))
colnames(res1) <- letters[seq_len(ncol(res1))]
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('gender', 'age', 'city', 'education')
```

Comment: Thanks you, @akrun

Comment: @akrun why these conditions on line 4?  for me it works perfectly well just doing: `lapply(seq_along(v1),combn,x=v1) %>% {do.call(cbind.fill,c(.,fill=NA))} %>% setNames(letters[1:ncol(.)])`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  Because the `combn(v1, 1)` gives a vector.  I am not sure if you got the same output

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  Thanks, looks like it works as you suggested